# Moving Thunderbird mails from Ubuntu to Windows (Thunderbird)

Tags: thunderbird

I currently have an Ubuntu work machine, where I'm using Thunderbird as my mail client. How can I export my mail/contacts/etc. to a Windows machine, that is also running Thunderbird.

I know that normally, you can just copy .thunderbird, on Linux, but I'm not sure if the Windows version has a similar folder.

Comment: Have you considered if, when setting up your email account in either place in Thunderbird, setting the server to imap will retain the mail on the server and allow you to view it from any of your devices. Delete a mail from one of your devices and it will remove acess to it from the others too.

Answer (score 1):

The same structure of files exists, however it's possible some file may have hardcoded file paths in them.

The following resources, although not directly addressing Ubuntu -> Windows migration, have extensive documentation about moving Thunderbird profiles, they should help determining what is needed:

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_from_Windows_to_Linux
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Move_to_a_new_PC
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder_-_Thunderbird